# error implement Tabs using compileSdkVersion 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I have been flowing this tutorial by android,

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

and i cannot add tabs to the action bar, 
i get an error saying

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
```

I read somewhere the tabs are not supported anymore, 
I have resolved to using the Title Strip instead in the same tutorial wich works, great, but i prefer the tabs, 
what am i making wrong ?

here is my fragment activity,

```
package apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import apps.radwin.wintouch.R;
import apps.radwin.wintouch.adapters.aligmentAdapters.SwipeAdapterProjectSelection;

public class projectSelectionMainFragment extends FragmentActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ViewPager mainViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project_selection_main_fragment);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        /////////////////////////////////////////
        //////// Start Of Implementation ////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////


        mainViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.projectSelectionMainViewPager); // the main view pager

        SwipeAdapterProjectSelection swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapterProjectSelection(getSupportFragmentManager()); // calls the adapter and initlizes it

        mainViewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter); // sets the adapter





        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        /////start of action bar implementation////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // hide the given tab
            }

            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // probably ignore this event
            }
        };

        // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.project_selection_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

error log:

```
                                                              Process: apps.radwin.wintouch, PID: 32161
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apps.radwin.wintouch/apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.projectSelectionMainFragment}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.projectSelectionMainFragment.onCreate(projectSelectionMainFragment.java:74)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "apps.radwin.wintouch"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 21
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.fenjuly:ArrowDownloadButton:9e15b85e8a'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.yayandroid:LocationManager:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.2'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered, by removing the old Action bar Implementation and inserting the new 
Tabllayout implementation as stated by android,

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsLayoutWorkorderSelection);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mainViewPager);
```

as it is implemented in the new `tabbed activity` you can do when you open a new Activity in Android.

in that case the Class can extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
 final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

set

```
 setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
```

EDIT: yea i miss

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

after u initialize toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of extending `FragmentActivity` because `AppCompatActivity` inherits from `FragmentActivity` and you need to set your `Toolbar` as your `ActionBar`. also make sure your base themes parent is  `AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` something like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and include

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

after

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

and get reference with `getSupportActionBar();` not `getActionBar();`

Comment: i tried it it's still the same error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object

Comment: still the same error, "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

First set Toolbar as action bar

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Instead of

```
  final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Please use

```
  final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

> Also make sure intheme/style that you have mentioned
>   windowActionBar as true or in activity
>   getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

Comment: it tried it, it errors out, "Tabs not supported in this configuration"

Comment: @ChiefMadog your error has changed right. Please update the question with new error logs.